PySpark basic question - who runs the Python code and how after all?
I am following a video course on Spark. I installed and so I now am running Spark on Windows.
I got to the point where I submit a python script via spark-submit to Spark.
Say the submitted Python script is test.py.
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf1 = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf1)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///D:/Taming-Big-Data-With-Apache-Spark-Hands-On/ml-100k/u.data")

ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))

I see that spark-submit is just a Windows cmd line script which runs Java.
My question is what happens with that submitted Python code?
Is it executed by my Python env (Anaconda in my case), or by the Spark Java code itself?

If it's executed by my Python env, does that mean I need to have this pyspark module already installed in my Python env?

If it's executed by Spark Java code, how does that work really? Does it mean Spark has a built-in Python interpreter?


I am quite confused, I need to understand the inner workings of this.
Are there some official docs which explain these inner workings with some diagrams maybe?
So far the video course has just asked me to setup two environment variables.
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
SPARK_HOME=C:\Programs\Spark-3.5.1-Hadoop3
I already had JAVA_HOME anyway.
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.16.1_1
As said, I wonder how these things interact once I call spark-submit.

Why was the answer given by Elmer Urbina Meneses deleted here? It seems it was deleted by another user Dalija Prasnikar. Why is that?! The answer had 4 upvotes and it was looking correct to me.
